# On hover stop animation at their respective position

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two divs which has one circle along with one smily where **innercircle1** div is rotating with given animation.
What i want is when i hover on **innercircle1** div it should stop but with their current transform origin position,
Currently when i hover over **innercircle1** div it goes to their starting point i.e. their given transform origin and stop.

```css
   body {
        background: #000;
        color: #fff;
    }

    @keyframes circle {
        from {
            transform: rotate(0deg);
        }

        to {
            transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
    }

    @keyframes inner-circle {
        from {
            transform: rotate(0deg);
        }

        to {
            transform: rotate(-360deg);
        }
    }

    .outercircle {
        border: 1px solid red;
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 310px;
        margin: 64px auto;
        height: 310px;
        position: Relative;
    }

    .innercircle {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        margin: 20px auto 0;
        color: orange;
        font-size: 100px;
        line-height: 1;
        animation: circle 5s linear infinite;
        transform-origin: 50% 200px;
        position: ABSOLUTE;
        top: -70px;
        left: 109px;
    }

    .innercircle1 {
        animation: inner-circle 5s linear infinite;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="outercircle"><div class="innercircle"><div class="innercircle1">☻</div></div></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pause animation using JQUERY as well as CSS.

A very simple solution to use animation-play-state property. 
Try these lines:

```
    .innercircle1 {
        animation: inner-circle 5s linear infinite;
        animation-play-state: play;
    }
   .innercircle1:hover{
        animation-play-state: paused;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks its done, but can u suggest me that how can we do with Jquery?

Comment: @WebStarter, look here how can you do with JQuery: http://codepen.io/gabrieleromanato/pen/jEfbn